# Customize Cursor Position in SLComposeViewController textview

Tags: ios, textview, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to change cursor position in textview of `SLComposeViewController` to beginning of `UITextView`
currently is show me the end of initial Text: 
[Currently Cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQor6.png)

but I want cursor at first position in `UITextView`. with (iOS 9 support) 
I also use this code

```
    [self presentViewController:sharingComposer animated:NO completion:^{
        for (UIView *viewLayer1 in sharingComposer.view.subviews) {
            for (UIView *viewLayer2 in viewLayer1.subviews) {
                if ([viewLayer2 isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                    for (UIView *viewLayer3 in viewLayer2.subviews) {
                        if ([viewLayer3 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                            [(UITextView *)viewLayer3 setDelegate:self];
                            sharingTextView = (UITextView *)viewLayer3;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

but i can't get sharing `UITextView` and not working for me.

Comment: Did you manage to get the UITextView with above code? I can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
UITextPosition *beginning = [sharingTextView beginningOfDocument];
[sharingTextView setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                                      toPosition:beginning]];
```

Comment: Your code will work if placed in the completion handler.

Comment: I Worte in completion handler and also use delayed but it got only on subview of viewlayer1, not even excute  if ([viewLayer3 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                            [(UITextView *)viewLayer3 setDelegate:self];
                            sharingTextView = (UITextView *)viewLayer3;
                        }

Comment: Try by removing the delay.

Comment: it not getting single subview for viewLayer1with above code